# Can we add Redis to Dart's get started web app?

Tags: dart, web, redis

I want to write my own program.
For that I chose the Dart language and I used the [tutorial: get started with a web app](https://dart.dev/tutorials/web/get-started)

My program to work needs a de-serialization of the data coming from Redis. And for the moment here it blocks.

> An external python program serialize data with JSON and use `lpush` to send data on Redis.

I have a compilation error on web server and I can't get out of it.

```
//library db.redis;
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:redis/redis.dart';
//import 'package:redis_client/redis_client.dart';
//import 'package:redis';

Iterable<String> thingsTodo() sync* {
    yield "walk the dog";
    yield "wash the dog";
}

LIElement newLI(String itemText) => LIElement()..text = itemText;

void main() {
    querySelector('#output')?.children.addAll(thingsTodo().map(newLI));
    const jsonString = '{"text": "Your app is running", "value": 1, "status": false, "extra": null}';

    final data = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    final conn = RedisConnection();

    //final client = await conn.connect('localhost');
    //conn.connect('localhost', 6379).then((Command command){
    //    command.send_object(["SET","key","0"]).then((var response)
    //        print(response);
    //    )
    //}

    //final client = await RedisClient.connect('localhost');
    //await client.set('name', 'Gabriel');

    //var res = await client.get('name');
    //print(res);

    //await client.close();

    querySelector('#end').text = data['text'];
}
```

When I try to add Redis, I always get an error message on the console with the `webdev serve` command.

The last:

> [WARNING] build_web_compilers:entrypoint on `web/main.dart`: Skipping
> compiling quickstart|web/main.dart with ddc because some of its
> transitive libraries have SDK dependencies that not supported on this
> platform:
>
> `redis|lib/redis.dart`
>
> https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-resolve-skipped-compiling-warnings

Answer (score 2):

You are compiling dart for the web (to JavaScript and HTML). And `redis` package is not supported there.

If you are trying to build actual web page, you are probably out of luck.

But if you want a console app (which I suppose is correct), try [this example](https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/get-started) instead. This will run script (`program`) on your system, instead of building web page.